# Strange MS Access Behavior - is this corruption?

Tags: database, microsoft-access

Not sure where to turn with this. We have no MS Access Experts, but of course, we have a bunch of Access databases floating around that people use

All of a sudden, on 4/1, a given database lost all of it's tables and queries. It is a shared database on a  network drive that the Finance team uses regularly. It also looks like it tries to repair itself upon opening.

After googling a bit, I saw someone mention that the objects may be hidden. I set it to show hidden objects, and some came up, but our Finance team said there are still things missing.

Is this corruption or perhaps a user just accidentally did something? The database has internal queries as well as linked queries to our SQL Servers. Not sure if that matters. There is also a chance that multiple versions of access are being used to open the files. They are MDB format.

Any guidance is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you restored from your daily backup?

Comment: Hilarious. :) They had a backup file they are using, but I was unsure if it would be usable going forward for them. I was mostly trying to understand *what* is wrong, so I can figure out what I need to do to fix it. I don't know how corruption manifests with Access databases.

Comment: More information - all user tables and queries were owned by "Engine". I wonder if someone upgrade the file? I can't remove the hidden attribute from any of these objects. What gives?